# MDL Checkbox check from JavaScript

Tags: jquery, material-design, material-design-lite

Below is the code and fiddle where I'm trying to un/check an [MDL checkbox](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#toggles-section/checkbox). It's state/UI/Design is not updating upon getting un/check. Have tried [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416822/1432033), but it didn't work.

```
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
    <input id="MdlCheckBox" type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" value='0' />
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Check Me</span>
</label>
<input type='button' value='check/uncheck' id='btn' />
```

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var chk = $("#MdlCheckBox")[0];
    chk.checked = chk.checked ? false : true;
    $(".mdl-checkbox__label").html(chk.checked ? "Check Me (Unchecked)" : "Check Me (Checked)");


    // below is SO solution tried but giving error
    var mdlComp = new MaterialCheckbox(chk);
    mdlComp.check();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aLfqkL4q/1/

Comment: `$("#MdlCheckBox")[0];` could be just `("#MdlCheckBox");` right?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao `[0]` is needed to access `checked`.

Comment: I am surprised that why haven't you tried the accepted answer there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to target the label, not the input. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80mfmnw4/)

```
<label id="check" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
    <input id="MdlCheckBox" type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" value='0' />
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Check Me</span>
</label>
<input type="button" value="test check" id="btn"/>
```

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    if($('#check').is('.is-checked')) {
    document.querySelector('#check').MaterialCheckbox.uncheck();
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector('#check').MaterialCheckbox.check();
  }
});
```