# JavaScript to Toggle Material Design Lite Switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, material-design

I have the following [Material Design Lite switch](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-switch) in my HTML and is looking for some javascript help.

```
<label  class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" checked />
    <span class="mdl-switch__label">USEREMAIL Subscribed</span>
</label>
```

Upon clicking the switch, I'd like to add:

1. Toggle functionality to update the checked to unchecked - like on and off switch, but is looking for JavaScript help here.
2. I would like to really have values of "subscribed" and "unsubscribed" as text that is displayed next to it as shown (but hardcoded in the html). Is this feasible to change dynamically?

Thanks for your time. I did find this [as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413042/toggle-material-design-lite-checkbox), but it was using CheckBox.

Answer (score 5):

If you refer to the mdl's [source code](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/switch/switch.js), you will find that the check and uncheck functions are bound with label tag.

You can specify an id to label like below:

```
<label id="check" class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input"/>
    <span class="mdl-switch__label">Subscribed</span>
</label>
<input type="button" value="test switch" id="btn"/>
```

MDL natively supports on/off status switch on button click. You can also control the status by another button.

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    if($('#check').is('.is-checked')) {
        $('#check')[0].MaterialSwitch.off();
    }
    else {
        $('#check')[0].MaterialSwitch.on();
    }
});
```

To update the switch label dynamically, the code can be put like below. Bind the  input's change event on page load and update label text if the on/off status changes.

```
//toggle label
$('#check input').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).next().text("Unsubscribed");
    else
        $(this).next().text("Subscribed");
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/theresa/ans6833m/12/). The answer comes a bit late for you but I hope it still helps.

Comment: The btn handler is not triggering the MDL Listener. I think you need to trigger the change listeners at the end of the #btn click handler with something like thsi:
$("#check input").trigger("change");

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the code in [above question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36902572/2192488):

```js
var myCheckbox = document.getElementById('switch-1');

myCheckbox.parentElement.MaterialSwitch.off();
…
myCheckbox.parentElement.MaterialSwitch.on();
```

Answer (score -2):

Below code maybe solve your problem:

```
var isChecked = $('#switch-1').is(':checked');
if(isChecked) {
    alert("subscribed");
} else {
    alert("not subscribed");
}
```